# How do I abort a PHP script which is triggered in browser? How it can be done?

Tags: php, email

I have a php script which sends bulk emails, this script is loaded in the browser. But in some scenarios I would like to stop the execution, even after the script is loaded in the browser. But the script executes in the server end and sends all the emails.

Comment: without seeing the script, it is impossible to answer

Answer (score 0):

This possible, if you have access to your web server.

On UNIX like systems:

1. `ps aux | grep php` - will list to you `PID` of php
2. `kill -9 PID` - will stop process

On windows you can do it via task manager. Just find in process list php and stop it.

Also you can stop script by timer of some condition. Then use `exit()/die()` function.